# Getting Word Frequency From Vector In c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, words

I have googled this question and couldn't find an answer that worked with my code so i wrote this to get the frequency of the words the only issue is that i am getting the wrong number of occurrences of words apart form one that i think is a fluke. Also i am checking to see if a word has already been entered into the vector so i don't count the same word twice.

```
fileSize = textFile.size();
vector<wordFrequency> words (fileSize);
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= fileSize - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < fileSize - 1; j++)
    {
        if(string::npos != textFile[i].find(textFile[j]) && words[i].Word != textFile[j])
        {
            words[j].Word = textFile[i];
            words[j].Times = index++;
        }
    }
    index = 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting more no of occurrences than expected?? And what does the find member function of textfile do in your program???

Comment: @bhuwansahni yes i am getting one that is right. The find is a vector function that looks for matching strings.

Comment: And what does find return on failure and succcess??

Comment: @bhuwansahni if there is success it adds the word and the number of times it has occurred and if it fails it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Will you post the code for your find fuction here??

Comment: @bhuwansahni There is no code for the find function it is part of the vector library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code instead if you do not want to use a map container..

```
    struct wordFreq{
    string word;
    int count;
    wordFreq(string str, int c):word(str),count(c){}
    };
vector<wordFreq> words;

int ffind(vector<wordFreq>::iterator i, vector<wordFreq>::iterator j, string s)
{
    for(;i<j;i++){
        if((*i).word == s)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code for finding the no of occurrences in a textfile vector is then:

```
for(int i=0; i< textfile.size();i++){
    if(ffind(words.begin(),words.end(),textfile[i]))    // Check whether word already checked for, if so move to the next one, i.e. avoid repetitions
        continue;
    words.push_back(wordFreq(textfile[i],1));          // Add the word to vector as it was not checked before and set its count to 1
    for(int j = i+1;j<textfile.size();j++){            // find possible duplicates of textfile[i]
        if(file[j] == (*(words.end()-1)).word)
            (*(words.end()-1)).count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Needed a bit of tweaking but got it working now thanks for the help.

Comment: Ouch... this is awkward! It is much simpler to use a `map` or `unordered_map` class!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `std::map<std::string,int>` instead. The map class will handle ensuring that you don't have any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Using an associative container:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned> WordFrequencies;

WordFrequencies count(std::vector<std::string> const& words) {
  WordFrequencies wf;
  for (std::string const& word: words) {
    wf[word] += 1;
  }
  return wf;
}
```

It is hard to get simpler...

*Note: you can replace `unordered_map` with `map` if you want the worlds sorted alphabetically, and you can write custom comparisons operations to treat them case-insensitively.*